# Architecture of the interface part for a Qt application

Tags: qt, class, architecture, qt4, uml

I'm new to software architecture, and application specification. 
I need write the specification of a project, where I need to have a CLI and a GUI (the GUI needs to be optional).

I've made a class diagram of the interfaces part and I need some feedback from people better than me.

[image: Class Diagram]

**Explanations :**

I am using Qt. The idea is to have a graphical interface with 3 tabs in order to change the parameters.

GUI is my main window, it contains the 3 pages who derived from QWidget (in order to put them into my QTabWidget).

CLI is my command line interface, it's in reality a QtScript class, who run in an infinite loop and wait for the user to enter a command.

Once the user click "save configuration" or enter "saveConf()" in the CLI, the parameters of GUI or CLI are transmited into ActualConfiguration.

The AllParameters class is used to add every parameters in my 3 class easily.

ActualConfiguration will write the parameters value into a file.

**EDIT:** After some answer, I'm thinking of using AllParameters as an instance used by CLI GUI and ActualParameters (See the Class Diagram who have been edited too)

**Questions :**

Is my architecture is going to work ?

Is it good if in order to comunicate with my application core, I write the configuration into a file, and read it with my application core ?

Have you any idea/comments/advice to give me ?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, no. The dependency should be shown differently that generalization. And the parent class is CLASS. You can to connect UI to pages as 1:1 compositions, but don't forget to write these multiplicities.

Comment: When something is derived from something else, put it there as another class block or at leas as Child:Parent in block header

Comment: Thanks, I've edited once again my diagram, my main idea was to inherite CLI GUI and ActualConfiguration from AllParameters, but I'm thinking of using an instance of AllParameters in order to handle the parameters of GUI CLI and the ActualParameters in real time from my interfaces. (I've added multiplicities too)

Comment: 1) Make 1 to 1 multiplicities on compositions GUI-Tab1,2,3. 2)Your tabs look the same now and it is not clear, why you need different classes for them - don't forget to fill them. 3) The note for them is excessive now. 4) The words page1,2,3 should appear on the tab send of the appropriate connection, you needn't them in the UI block. 5) the connection UI-AllParam make association and put the attribute name param on the AllParam end of the association. Set multiplicity here, too. The same for Cli and ActualConfigurations.

Comment: You can make GUI.setLayout(QWidget) and thus serve all three pages. (if you need, of course).

Comment: Are you sure you need the same attribute in three classes? Can they provide it to each other?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's a lot better now, diagram edited. Do I put the attributes names on the good side of the association ? I really think yes, I need all my attributes in each classes, I'm gonna think again a lot to see if it's really needed.

Comment: If class A takes the instance of C from the class B and does not have a reference to in in A, then A block hasn't C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In really class part it has errors, and the lower part is not a class diagram at all.

- Do your pages have different classes?

  - If not, use only one Page and leave the association from Gui as you have it.
  - If yes, make a common parent type for them and set association from Gui to the parent.
- You have no multiplicities there
- `All parameters` is not a parent class really for all you have drawn there. It seems, you mixed Dependency( - - - - - > slashed line) and Generalization connectors.
- Two associations have no arrows. Are they really two-directional?

> "CLI is my command line interface, it's in reality a QtScript class,
>   who run in an infinite loop and wait for the user to enter a command.
>
> Once the user click "save configuration" or enter "saveConf()" in the
>   CLI, the parameters of GUI or CLI are transmited into
>   ActualConfiguration."

- Such things are not for showing in class diagram, but in a sequence diagram. Or, at least, activity or component one.

Comment: For AllParameters, I havn't understood, I just want to use it in order to not rewrite every possible parameters variables into my 3 class. Maybe GUI doesn't need it, and can directly pass the Qt UI values into ActualConfiguration, but CLI needs it, in order to write "param1 = 5;" in the CLI, value who is stored in CLI and at the "saveParam()" call, it's transmitted to ActualConfiguration. (Architecture and UML are more complicated than expected) I'm editing my post for more informations, and the modified class diagram.

Comment: @MoKaT So, put generalization connection from pages to their parent and connect the parent to the UI. In each of the page classes make these unique parameters.

Comment: For the pages, my pages are 3 class derived from QWidget in order to put them into a QTabWidget (GUI), where each one have the parameters fields of a module in my application (like page1 contains options fields for functionality 1, page2 contains options fields for functionality 2, ...) the GUI class contain my main windows, where I'm gonna put my tabs (my pages).

Comment: I have answered before you have asked :-)

Comment: @MoKaT Then your classes have dependencies with <u> (use) on them as connections to AllParameters

Answer (score 0):

This diagram is not necessarily bad or good because it can implemented quite differently.

> I need to have a CLI and a GUI (the GUI needs to be optional) 
>   ... 
>    Once the user ..., the parameters of GUI or CLI are transmited into ActualConfiguration.

From what I see the user interface (GUI or CLI) should expose the same API to the other components. Either via signal and slots, composition or inheritance of a common class (my least desired choice when using Qt).

At the same time you need another component which provide the API for the processing. So 
`UI API` provide user request to `Processing API`, which executes and return feedback to `UI API`.

Your architecture need to be very simple to be scalable. When you start designing software you are tempted to make a custom architecture which is very complex. What if the number of user input change from 3 to 30? What if you have more parameters in the future? Is it easy to keep track of the data flow in my app?

All of this chit-chat to say you should probably follow a [three-tier or two tier architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-tier_architecture#Three-tier_architecture) (which is similar to the [mvc pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller))

Comment: It's going to be a card reader simulator, so there is no processing exept "run simulation with these parameters", does ActualParameters can be the Processing API ? and GUI and CLI the UI API ? I can, at every user interaction, give to ActualParameters the modified values with signals/slots. I have not put all my diagram in the post, I have, speratly from this part, the actual Simulator class (who is the real processing class of my application)

Comment: The diagram is no UML at all.